# Set OCR Language with OneNote COM-API

Tags: python, ms-office, ocr, onenote, onenote-api

I use the OneNote COM API and Python to recognize text from an image. To load a new image, I use method "UpdatePageContent" and it works very well.

```
import traceback
import win32com.client
def oneAddImage(OneNoteObject, PageID):
    try:
        ImagePath = r"C:\TestDir\TestImage.png"
        newContent = u'<?xml version="1.0"?><one:Page xmlns:one="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote" ID="%s"><one:PageSettings RTL="false" color="automatic"><one:PageSize><one:Automatic/></one:PageSize><one:RuleLines visible="false"/></one:PageSettings><one:Image format="png" originalPageNumber="0"><one:Position x="36.0" y="86.4000015258789" z="0"/><one:File path="%s"/></one:Image></one:Page>'%(PageID, ImagePath)

        OneNoteObject = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('OneNote.Application')

        OneNoteObject.UpdatePageContent(newContent, xsSchema=win32com.client.constants.xs2013)

    except Exception:
        print(str(traceback.format_exc()))
        return False
```

My question is how can I set the language to be used by the OCR service when loading the image?

Answer (score 0):

Once the service sees your image without a language id, it should automatically recognize it. Is this not what you are seeing?

Comment: No, if I do not enter a language, OCR uses the default language.

In this case, I want to do the same about the API as in the picture.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXUvK.png